# Where is the boost lib subdirectory?

Tags: boost

Hi I downloaded the latest boost library (.7z format) yesterday, after unzipping, I found there is no lib subdirectory here, so I cannot find any .lib files, is it the oversight of boost team?

The directory structure I have:

boost_1_51_0

- boost
- doc
- libs
- more
- status
- tools
- etc

Comment: 8()  you have to build it! Did you read docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of boost's capabilities are in header only files inside the `boost` directory. Which means all you need to do is include the `boost` directory in your project and you're done.

For a few specific libraries you'll need to build your own lib via the [instructions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/more/getting_started/index.html) on Boost's site.

If you're using Eclipse with CDT (which is harder to configure) there are better instructions [here](http://theseekersquill.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/howto-boost-mingw/).